# What was Finn going to tell Rey?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

As Rey and Finn are sinking into the desert, Finn shouts that he has something he wanted to tell Rey, but they are swallowed before he can say it.

Later, Poe asks Finn what he was going to say, but doesn't get an answer.

What was Finn going to say?

Comment: We don’t know, they deliberately left it vague but it seems likely he was going to say he loves her or something like that.

Comment: I dont think there is a definite answer for this yet but my guess is "I love you"

Comment: "Your hair smells nice."

Comment: If it was "I love you", he must've just swallowed it down when he saw her make out with her new literally-her-soul-mate boyfriend.  It was weird that he walked in and saw her collapse, and then completely vanished for the remainder of the scene.

Comment: The actor has since stated outright that it was not a declaration of love. https://twitter.com/JohnBoyega/status/1209077504914444288

Comment: *Whatever would make you think higher of the film*. If only they'd said *this*, everything would make sense! Clever move by the writers.

Comment: It seems like any answer to this question will be speculation, because the movie is so deliberately vague. I've seen that be a reason to close before, would that apply here? (Sorry to be a buzzkill, I enjoy speculation as much as anybody.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Reportedly J.J. Abrams told a [fan](https://twitter.com/ar1aster/status/1208293387310264320?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1208293387310264320&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fcomicbook.com%2Fstarwars%2F2019%2F12%2F22%2Fstar-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-finn-wanted-tell-rey%2F) at a recent event that Finn wanted to tell her he was Force-sensitive.

> *I had the privilege of attending the Academy screening of #TheRiseOfSkywalker today and J.J. confirmed that what Finn wanted to tell Rey was that he’s force sensitive!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/ar1aster/status/1208293387310264320?s=21)</sup></sub>

I say “reportedly” because Abrams has not yet confirmed this in an on-the-record interview. But when a fan asked John Boyega [the same question on Instagram](https://twitter.com/kyberswift/status/1208209739403972608?s=21), he responded

> “it’s an instinct... a feeling.”

So that’s two inside sources stating or hinting at the Force explanation. I’d argue the context in the movie strongly hints towards the romantic explanation (why would he say that when they were about to die? Why hide it? Why later refuse to tell Poe?), but it is what it is.

Comment: Counter point: Finn may be sensitive on the issue.  He may *think* he is force sensitive, but that doesn't mean he *knows and can prove* he is force sensitive.  The closest thing to a Jedi master that we know he knows and trusts is Rey, and he would likely prefer to seek counsel and confirmation before telling others.  Surely everyone would *want* to be force sensitive, to be able to be "the best fighter we've got" like Rey.  Best to get tested before telling people who might dismiss you as having childish delusions you can't corroborate beyond "I have a feeling".

Comment: A guy will say anything to try to impress a girl: I got the force now, too, baby.

Comment: There’s an article on the Independent website that agrees JJ said its about force sensitivity.

Comment: Confirmed pretty strongly by novelization ....

Answer (score 7):

I wondered if it was that he has feelings for her, then I had another thought: could he have been wanting to tell her he’s Force sensitive? It was alluded to several times in the movie.

Comment: Whilst an answer, this reads more as a comment. You should [edit] it into more of an actual answer.

Comment: I think you're right, but your answer needs to be expanded. Since they never say definitively what he was going to say, then any answer will be necessarily speculative. However, you can support your claim by giving instances of Finn demonstrating potential force sensitive stuff (he feels things others don't, etc). Then sum up by saying he would want to tell Rey, who is the only person who could guide him in what to do.